# Two classes Have the same XML type name …”

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Getting the JAXB exception like "Two classes have the same XML type name..."

However those are 3rd party libraries plus the xml generated is used by another apps in which there aren't a mapping for a different annotation in attributes.

Could be there another approach to solve this issue?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "status". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at com.test.mx.PersonBO$Status
                at public com.test.mx.PersonBO$Status com.test.mx.PersonBO.getPersonStatus()
                at com.test.mx.PersonBO
                at public com.test.mx.PersonBO com.test.mx.ReportHeaderTO.getPersonCreator()
                at com.test.mx.ReportHeaderTO
                at private com.test.mx.ReportHeaderTO com.test.mx.common.QueueXml.header
                at com.test.mx.common.QueueXml
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at com.test.mx.ReportTO$Status
                at public com.test.mx.ReportTO$Status com.test.mx.ReportHeaderTO.getStatus()
                at com.test.mx.ReportHeaderTO
                at private com.test.mx.ReportHeaderTO com.test.mx.common.QueueXml.header
                at com.test.mx.common.QueueXml
```

Comment: It would be nice to see pertinent XML data and code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think I can get the code but the generated xml I don't have it because this fail, would be enough with those 2 classes?

Comment: I'm not sure. Hopefully [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) will drive by ([blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/)) and help solve this. He is the JAXB king.